# Can not import soundfile when double click on win7?

Tags: python, windows

I make a code test.py like this:

```
import soundfile
print("import success")
```

when I try to run this on windows 7， I can only run successfully by cmd：

```
python test.py
```

but I cannot run it by double click on test.py, it's too fast to dispear, I can see it display:

```
no module named soundfile
```

And I notice that, when I double click test.py on windows 10, it successed.

Comment: Your Windows 7 system is probably set up to execute a different Python interpreter than the one you expect when you double-click on a .py file, and in that Python environment, `soundfile` is not installed.

Comment: @BoarGules Thx, I dont know how to change the python environment of double-click. How could it be different with python in cmd.

Comment: The double-click configuration is in your registry, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command`.

Answer (score 0):

THX to @BoarGules, by using

```
where python
```

in cmd.
I replace python path from python2.7 to python3 in regedit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command .
Then double-click working!